# Excel export with apache POI driving me crazy

Tags: excel, fonts, apache-poi, java

using smartgwt on tomcat running on openjdk on debian squeeze.

I have a grid on my site which you can excel-export. It transfers to server and it exports the data using Apache POI. You then get a popup in the browser so that you can save the excel file.

When running Tomcat locally, all works fine - however on my debian server, the Excel file looks empty when i open it. It IS not empty since if i save it as CSV i can see the data. MY colleague opened it on his phone and could look at the data. However in Excel 11 on Mac or Windows the file appears blank...

I think it has something to do with the Fonts installed on the server, so i have installed the "ttf-mscorefonts-installer" package that contains the Microsoft truetype fonts via apt-get, but still no success. I've tried copying fonts, using both XSL and OOXSL, but to no avail.

has anyone had any experience with this? I feel like i've tried everything now.

Comment: Did you try creating a file with Excel itself, then having Tomcat return that in place of the generated file? That would at least let you identify if the issue is with the file generation, or with the file serving

Comment: That's not a bad idea mate, will try and get back here. I suspect it will work fine though...

Comment: Next up, try creating a simple "Hello World" excel file on the server, no styling or anything, and see how that one works. That should narrow it down to styling vs everything POI

Comment: Yeah, i created a simple JSP that saved a file, basically straight from this example: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/424.html Looks fine in all Excelprograms... So it's gotta be something with how smartGWT creates the Excelfile, more specifically what styling is applied right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others: This was caused by certain fonts not being available in OpenJDK, without any errors being logged anywhere.

I switched to Sun's JDK on my Debian as well, and the Excel files now open and display properly.